# How do I write html in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to write an html and css draft bord in javascript.

```
//I tried 
document.write()
//and
document.(my element).innerHTML
```

But I need 1 more alternate method

Please help out

Comment: We have absolutely no idea what you mean. Please edit your question and explain it more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append childs to your DOM Elements like a list for example:

```
var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");         // Create a text node
node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);     // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"
```

Check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp